# Autoincrementing strings

Tags: php, auto-increment

I'm trying to build a hierarquical list of categories, like this:

```
1 Category
  1.1 Children
  1.2 Children
      1.2.1 Children
```

Here's my code:

```
$a = "1.1";
echo ++$a; // 2.1

$b = "1.1.1";
echo ++$b; // 1.1.2
```

Why `$a` increments to **2.1** instead of **1.2** like `$b`?

Comment: PHP doesn't increment float numbers. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666218/increment-decimal-floating-point-numbers

Comment: Buddy, your incrementing it by 1(one) not by 0.1 .`u can try $a = "1.1";
echo $a=$a+(1/10); `

Comment: i would use `echo $a + 0.1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"1.1"` parses to the float value `1.1`, and anyone can tell you that `1.1 + 1 = 2.1`

However, `"1.1.1"` can't be parsed into a number, so it is treated as a string. PHP supports `++` for strings in different ways in an attempt to be useful, however this is only really successful for letters (`A` through `Z`, then `AA`, `AB`...).

Answer (score 1):

try `$a = "1.1"; echo $a=$a+(1/10);` instead.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try `$a = 1.1; echo $a + 0.1;`
i think this is that what you want